# Multiple CLR schemas in Visual Studio SSDT project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, sqlproj

I'm trying to have a single `sqlproj` project in Visual Studio 2022, representing my SQL Server database.

When creating a CLR stored proc or function in C#, the `SqlFunction` or `SqlProcedure` attribute has a `Name` property, but not a schema. It seems the entire project will use the default schema. I'd like to be able to have more than one schema with CLR items.

I've found a couple different ways of moving procs from one schema to another after deployment, but is there any way to get it right in the first place?

For example, by default, if I create a `MyProc` procedure, I can reference it as `dbo.MyProc` from a regular proc. But I want that to live in the `other` schema. Even if I change schemas as a post-deploy step, then my regular procs with `EXEC [other].[MyProc]` will not compile properly in Visual Studio since it thinks it's referencing a non-existent procedure.

I don't want multiple projects because I want fully-functional schema compare and publish steps for the whole database.

Comment: I think that you can disable the "Generate DDL" option and then add you own script for creating the SQL side of the CLR proc.